# Column value become Nan when converted to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm transforming the mean of data per day, into a dataframe. The code is as below:

```
#find the mean
mean_paymentAmount= data_2015.groupby('paymentDate')['paymentAmount'].mean()
mean_loanAmount= data_2015.groupby('paymentDate')['loanAmount'].mean()

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Loan Amount"] = mean_loanAmount
df["Payment Amount"] = mean_paymentAmount
df["Payment Date"] = paymentDate
paymentDate.reset_index()
df
```

What should I fix so that the index at right of table become a proper index (0 to 1) and the 'payment date' become as one proper column?

Answer (score 0):

## Instead,Create a dataFrame like this..

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["Loan Amount"] = loanAmount

df["Payment Amount"] = df_payment

df["Payment Date"] = paymentDate

Comment: payment Date column is still has Nan value..Edited question with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to insert the column `Payment Date`, since it´s already in dataframe´s index.

If you want to convert it into a column, use `paymentDate.reset_index()` instead of `insert`:

```
#find the mean
paymentDate = data_2015['paymentDate']
mean_paymentAmount= data_2015.groupby('paymentDate')['paymentAmount'].mean()
mean_loanAmount= data_2015.groupby('paymentDate')['loanAmount'].mean()
df = mean_loanAmount.to_frame()
df_payment = mean_paymentAmount.to_frame()

#transform into dataframe
df.columns = ["Loan Amount"]
df.insert(1, "Payment Amount", df_payment, True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: index doesnt work..Edited question with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works -

```
df = data_2015.groupby(['paymentDate']).agg(mean_payment=('paymentAmount', 'mean'), mean_loan=('loanAmount', 'mean')).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Payment Date', 'Payment Amount', 'Loan Amount']
```